# Notice: Undifined variable: [value]

Tags: php, html, database, authentication, web

I have searched on stackoverflow about the undifined variable, and I couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

this is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['naam']);
    $password =md5( $_POST['wacht']);

    $check_user = "select * from users where gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam' AND wachtwoord='$wachtwoord'";

    $run =mysql_query($check_user);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    $_SESSION['naam']=$gebruikersnaam;

        echo "<script>window.open('welkom.php','_self')</script>";
    }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id=content>
    <form method='POST' action='login.php'>
        Gebruikersnaam:<br>
        <input type='text' name='naam' />
        <br>
        <br>
        Wachtwoord:<br>
        <input type='password' name='wacht' />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit' name='login' value='Inloggen' />
    </form>
    <br>
    Niet geregistreerd? <a href='registratie.php'>Klik hier.</a>
</div>
```

I can't see where my problem is, it says I have a undefined variable on this line: `$check_user = "select * from users where gebruikersnaam='$gebruikersnaam' AND wachtwoord='$wachtwoord'";`

The names I use are from my database so I wouldn't make a mistake with the names.

Could you people help me? It would be a real time saver because I can't find the problem.

Comment: Don't assume because the submit button is pressed that the values are set. Use `isset` on all `$_POST` items.

Comment: maybe you didnt define  $gebruikersnaam  or $wachtwoord?

Comment: @Script47 i do use the isset on all post items, the check_user i inside the isset.

Comment: You are assigning to a variable before using `isset`.

Comment: @NanaPartykar the gebruikersnaam and wachtwoord

Comment: Replace your query by `$check_user = "select * from users where gebruikersnaam='$username' AND wachtwoord='$password'";`

Comment: `check_user` is just a string. It doesn't checks anything

Comment: @Script47 well my PHP code is below the HTML and i i try it on a test page it does work

Comment: @AnkiiG i have changed my ode with yours now it does not show the variable but now i can't login, it doesn't do anything

Comment: Do this and check the number of rows returned `echo mysql_num_rows($run);`

Comment: Check result of `mysql_num_rows($run);`

Comment: @AnkiiG i have found a another fault in my code i used $username and $password in my post but it needs to be $gebruikersnaam and $wachtwoord

Comment: you can name the variables as you want but the fields in the database table must match the query where condition clause @Gandalf

Comment: @AnkiiG yea i am aware of that, but as i said earlier i did copy the names of the rows in my database so i wouldn't screw up with the names typed incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not check if the following variables are set before you assign them.

```
$_POST['naam']
$_POST['wacht']
```

As you did with `$_POST['login']` you can use `isset` to check they exist before assignment.

```
if (isset($_POST['naam'] && isset($_POST['wacht']) {
    // Do something...
}
```

In addition to this in the query you are using the variables `$gebruikersnaam` and `$wachtwoord` which you don't appear to be referencing anywhere else? So after some google translating I'm guessing that you intended for this bit of code:

```
$username =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['naam']);
$password =md5( $_POST['wacht']);
```

To be the following:

```
$gebruikersnaam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']);
$wachtwoord     = md5($_POST['wacht']);
```

Hopefully that helps, just a bit of a side note though, I would really advise reading over http://www.phptherightway.com/ and getting familiar with some of the best practices for PHP.

In your code I would attempt to refactor it and utilise `password_hash()` and `mysqli_*` as `MD5()` is not secure and the `mysql_` extension has been removed in the latest version of PHP and was deprecated before that.

Comment: mmm ok, can i replace the MD5 with password_hash on the same place?

Comment: There is a little bit more to it than that, the manual would be a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php I would like to give you a bit more information on it, but I don't have the time right now,

Answer (score 0):

Its just a typo I think, you create 2 variables called `$username` and `$password` but you are not using them in the query, the query is using `$gebruikersnaam` and `$wachtwoord`, which of course have not been defined.

So amend the query to this

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['naam']);
    $password =md5( $_POST['wacht']);

    $check_user = "SELECT * 
                   FROM users 
                   WHERE gebruikersnaam='$username' 
                     AND wachtwoord='$password'";

    $run =mysql_query($check_user);

    if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){

    $_SESSION['naam']=$gebruikersnaam;

        echo "<script>window.open('welkom.php','_self')</script>";
}
```

Additional Note:

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: can i simply replace the msql with mysli?

Comment: No I am afraid it is not quite that simple

Comment: yea, i have been reading now and it's really complex for me i was just getting the hang of mysql so yea....

Comment: The problem is the `mysql_` extension no longer exists in the new PHP7. So any code you write with `mysql_` will not run on that version of PHP. There is unfortunately nothing to do other than learn either `mysqli_` or `PDO` before you waste any more time on the `mysql_` extension